# Making a Java Application available via a Web Browser

Tags: java

I am working on a Java program that has bunch of classes consisting of dialog boxes, JFrames, etc.

Can someone guide me where I can learn how to transform it to an 'applet' kind of. ( I don't even know if applet is the right word)

Like for example, can it be accessible through the internet browser. If I somehow make a domain www.myjavaprogram2011.com  it would be nice if it will take it straight to the java program I coded. I see this as anyone can come to this website and use that program.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into Jars for distribution or probably more aptly [Java Web Start](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/index.html) as this allows Clients to be downloaded and run.

Comment: java web start...hmm this sounds like a good keyword to google. Thanks. I shall look in to this.

Answer (score 2):

Java Applets isn't your best bet as there's lots of security permissions that you need to worry about as well as your jars needs to be signed (especially for client/server data access).

Try using [Java Web Start](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/), it will allow you to launch fully-featured application from the Web Browser. Oracle has [tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html) on deployment of JWS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds you're looking for some kind of RIA technology. Have a look at JavaFX, though it's not mature yet IMHO.

Ah, but then, if you already have a Swing application then this isn't an option probably.